# Swift 4 How to remove %EF%BB%BF from URL created from URLComponent()?

Tags: ios, swift, url, nsurlcomponents

I attempt to create URL from components

```
var com =  URLComponents()
com.scheme = "http"
com.host = "192.168.1.99"
com.port = 77
com.path = "/api/dosomething/55"

print("SHOW ME URl =  \(com.url!))")
```

What I got is something like this

```
http://192.168.1.99:77/%EF%BB%BFapi/dosomething/55
```

Always got `%EF%BB%BF`, in which case the url becomes invalid

I want to remove `%EF%BB%BF`from the URL

How can I do that?

Comment: I can't, reproduce, when I copy-pasted your code, I got `SHOW ME URl =  http://192.168.1.99:77/api/dosomething/55)`/ Tested in Playground, Xcode 10.

Comment: `%EF%BB%BF` is an percent encoded byte sequence of ZERO WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE(aka BOM in UTF-16/UTF-32). In UTF-8, it's just an extra character. You may be taking the path component from some external resource. You may need to fix that part or the way creating the external resource.

Comment: For example, some Japanese-made editors show `UTF-8 with extra ZERO WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE` as **UTF-8**, and the right `UTF-8` as **UTF-8N**. You need  to use the right `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a URL-encoding of a UTF-8 [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), it may be caused by processing of the URLs with some text editors. Trim white spaces from your path string:

```
var com =  URLComponents()
com.scheme = "http"
com.host = "192.168.1.99"
com.port = 77
let path = //The path
let trimmedPath = path.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
com.path = trimmedPath

print("SHOW ME URl =  \(com.url!)")
```

In utf-8, the ['ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/index.htm) is encoded as `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF`

Comment: `.whitespaces` does not seem to contain the BOM character.

Answer (score 0):

**Direct answer to your question**

You can replace this pattern with nothing :

```
let theURL = "http://192.168.1.99:77/%EF%BB%BFapi/dosomething/55"
let partToRemove = "%EF%BB%BF"
let clearURL = theURL.replacingOccurrences(of: partToRemove, with: "")
print(clearURL)
```

Answer (score 0):

In complement to ielyamani's answer, as `.whitespaces` does not seem to contain the BOM character, I suggest this :

```swift
extension String
{
    var withoutBom: String
    {
        let bom = "\u{FEFF}"
        if self.starts(with: bom)
        {
            return String(dropFirst(bom.count))
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

and then using something like :

```swift
path.withoutBom
```